# How to read the last created file in a directory? vb.net

Tags: xml, vb.net, getfiles

I have a directory where xml documents are stored once created every minute.

I need to read the newest/latest xml document each time it is added.

Is there anyway i can read the newest/latest xml file from the directory?

Answer (score 1):

[FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) would be good for this.